# Como puedo concatenar un numero entero para convertir una fecha?

Tags: php, laravel, oracle

Estoy importando datos desde un excel hacia mi base de datos, pero hay un campo en específico que lo tengo que realizar de una manera diferente.

Por ejemplo, mi campo tiene esta forma en mi excel: *20200201* pero se me ha solicitado que la persona que esté llenando eso, que solo escriba *202002*  y que no escriba el último número, pero que a la hora de insertarlo, me inserte la fecha completa pero que siempre sea  *202002+01*. Tiene que ser siempre *01* de cada mes.

¿Hay alguna forma que pueda concatenar este dato y convertirlo  a una fecha?

Este es mi código donde leo los valores de mi excel:

```
class Usersimport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{


    public function model(array $row)
    {

*/en esta parte obtengo el valor de mi excel el cual me trae un numero y lo tengo que convertir para a fecha para poderlo insertar lo intente de esta forma pero no me funciona 


 $date =  strtotime($row['PERIODO']);

        $uno=1;
        $conversion="$date.\"\".$uno";
        $dat= date("Ymd H:i:s", $conversion);
*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



        $hoy = date("Y-m-d");
        $ahora= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $moneda='D';

        $tc_factura=25;


        return new importar([
            "PROVEEDOR"=> $row['PROVEEDOR'],
            "DESC_ENLACE" => $row['DESC_ENLACE'],
            "NO_FACTURA" => $row['NO_FACTURA'],
            "ID_ENLACE" => $row['ID_ENLACE'],
            "VALOR_PAGO" => $row['VALOR_PAGO'],
            "PERIODO" => $dat,
            "FECHA_FACTURA" => $hoy,
            "FECHA_INGRESO" => $ahora,
            "MONEDA" => $moneda,
            'TC_FACTURA' => $tc_factura,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sin importar que fecha sea ingresada, ¿ocupas que el espacio asignado al día se concatene con 01?

Comment: Es correcto sin importar la fecha siempre tiene que ser 01  (2020/02/01) siempre

Answer (score 0):

Basado en tus comentarios, puedo entender que todas las fechas tienen el mismo formato inicialmente y puedes transformarlas a `timestamp`. Por lo cual, la conversión la puedes realizar de la siguiente forma.

```
$date = '2020-5-20';
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
echo date("Y-m-01", $timestamp);
```

Comment: Wow... ¿todo ese código para algo tan sencillo?

Comment: como podria adaptarlo a mi codigo

Comment: El detalle que cuando guardo la variable $date =  strtotime($row['PERIODO']); que es el dato de mi excel mi fecha no me trae la fecha si no un numero entero y ese numero lo convierto a fecha como tengo ahi para luego insertarlo pero no se como en mi excel solo colocar 202002   y que siempre me concatene el 01 pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: @JuanCarlosVeliz He actualizado la respuesta luego de tu comentario.

Comment: @Shaz Tienes razón, inicialmente entendí mal el problema y los formatos de origen en las fechas, por eso el exceso de código.